# Add a new blank like in PSObject

Tags: powershell

This works but I want to add a new blank line after each line, something like `n

```
$objAverage = New-Object PSObject
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name FirstName-value $FirstName
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name LastName -value $LastName 
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name Office -value $Office
$objAverage | fl
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could append linefeeds to strings using .Net's [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) property like so,

```
$objAverage = New-Object PSObject
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name FirstName -value $("Winston"+[Environment]::NewLine)
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name LastName -value $("Smith"+[Environment]::NewLine)
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name Office -value $("Room 101"+[Environment]::NewLine)
$objAverage | fl
# Output:

FirstName : Winston

LastName  : Smith

Office    : Room 101




PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

One brutal way:

```
$FN = "Jack"
$LN = "Black"
$Of = "HR"    

$firstName = @"
$FN

"@

$LastName =  @"
$LN

"@

$Office = @"
$Of

"@    

$objAverage = New-Object PSObject
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name FirstName-value $FirstName
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name LastName -value $LastName 
$objAverage | Add-Member Noteproperty -name Office -value $Office
$objAverage | fl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify only the output, but not the actual data, you could do something like this:

```
($objAverage | fl | Out-String) -replace "(.`r`n)", "`$1`r`n"
```

The above converts the list output to a string and appends a newline (CR-LF) to all non-blank lines.